# onTapGesture fails whole appliaction

Tags: swift, xcode

I am making a little game with some youtube tutorials, I made the design but whenever I try to add `onTapGesture` my xCode returns an error `Cannot Preview This File`, and the simulator launches but it's just all white

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        HStack{
            CardView()
            CardView()
            CardView()
            CardView()
        }
        .foregroundColor(.orange)
        .padding(.horizontal)
    }
}
struct CardView:View {
    @State var isFaceUp:Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            let shape = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
            if isFaceUp {
                shape.stroke(lineWidth: 3)
                Text("‍♂️").font(.largeTitle)
            } else{
                shape.fill()
            }
        }
        onTapGesture {
            isFaceUp = !isFaceUp
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Correct the syntax and it'll fix the crash:**

```
struct CardView:View {
    @State var isFaceUp:Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            let shape = RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 20)
            if isFaceUp {
                shape.stroke(lineWidth: 3)
                Text("‍♂️").font(.largeTitle)
            } else{
                shape.fill()
            }
        }.onTapGesture {
            isFaceUp = !isFaceUp
        }
    }
}
```